# ioctl() call list for iOS

Tags: c, ios, system-calls, ioctl

Quickie: where (in which header files) can I find the declarations of the parameters of the ioctl() call on iOS? I've already looked at ioctl.h and the first-level includes it imports, but I'm not sure whether they're the only place to search through. In particluar, I'd be interested in using this function to control some special hardware features (like accessing the accelerometer or the vibrate motor).

Answer (score 2):

In the general sense, you can't know everywhere that an ioctl can be defined, because the parameters to ioctl are in general simply integers.

In practice, if you poke around the entire set of available .h files you'll find all sorts of things -- but Apple could easily conceal that from you by simply not supplying a particular .h file with the public SDK.